# How to create a custom react component in Form IO?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formio

There has been so little [documentation](https://help.form.io/developers/form-development/custom-components), [Github Issues](https://github.com/formio/react/issues) and examples (not on [react-app-startkit](https://github.com/formio/react-app-starterkit) though) of thoroughly creating custom components in Form IO with `Reactjs`, and it took me countless hours to figure something workable out.

Thus, I think it has the values to ask a question to organize the different methods available (with either functional or class components, as you like), and how they could interact with `<Form>` and `<FormBuilder>` components.

Below is the basic way mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.form.io/developers/form-development/custom-components) to create custom components in plain `JavaScript`:

```
const Input = Formio.Components.components.input;
class MyInput extends Input {
  ...
  ...
}
```

Thank you for all the help.